# Ionic : 2 How to control components & providers to hide/show by toggle button in settings page?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi Guys I am new to the ionic 2, In my project i need to create the advertisment On/Off button using toggle in settings page, already i created ads by providers and put wherever i want in some pages successfully, but i Excatly now want to do make control by on/off button for all ads for show and hide, so i used *ngIf but it cant work properly, then i stuck here for how to access control in setting page via providers.. can any one please help me.....

Like below images i need to work as toggle button for ads.(like this ads i inserted some more pages via provider successfully)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqQX0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APp4s.png)
Here Is my Code:

SETTINGS.TS:

```
public checked:boolean = true;
  public showMeAd: boolean;

  AdControl(e:any, showMeAd) {    
    if(e.checked == true){
    // console.log('advertisment on');
    alert('advertisment on');
    //showMeAd = true;
    }else{    
    alert('advertisment off');
    //showMeAd = false;
    }   
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="images" wp="md-images" ios="md-images" md="md-images" item-left ></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Advertisment</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="textRed" class="animated pulse delay1" (ionChange)="AdControl($event)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: what happen when you use `*ngIf` ?

Comment: while Use *ngIf i can hide by manually give boolean value in providers page, but i dont know how to make set for toggle button via providers.

Comment: here is the provider code :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { settings } from '../pages/settings/settings';
@Component({
  selector: 'addMiniSize',
  template:`        
    <ion-grid padding-vertical *ngIf="showMeAd">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col no-padding>
        some thing image or etc....
      </ion-col>         
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  `
})

Comment: please edit your question and add it there :)